# Select from multiple tables in asp.net

Tags: sql, sql-server

lets say I have 2 Tables:

**`USER`**:

- `Userid`(PK),
- `FirstName`,
- `LastName`.

**`ADDRESS`**:

- `Userid`(FK),
- `Street`,
- `City`.

Now I want to display following data in a `Table`:

```
|  userid  |  FirstName  |  LastName  |  Street | City
```

i need to get all entries so it would be nice if i could store the information in a `List` or something...

Comment: Have you already tried anything?

Comment: What technological restrictions do you have? What version of .net framework? Could you use Entity Framework? etc.

Comment: What are you using to access the database? You can select multiple tables into separate data tables.

Comment: I am using a DataTable for storing the information then i write it into a string-List which i can then access and write it's contents into the table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`JOIN`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29) the two tables:

```
SELECT
  u.userid,
  u.firstname,
  u.lastname,
  a.Street,
  a.City
FROM [User] AS u
INNER JOIN Address AS a ON u.userId = a.userid;
```

You might also need to use `LEFT JOIN` to include those users that has no email or city, see this article for more info about different `JOIN` types:

- [A visual explanation of SQL Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT   
 t1.userid  
 t1.FirstName 
 t1.LastName  
 t2.Street  
 t2.City  
FROM USER t1, ADDRESS t2
```

Comment: where's the joining condition? this will likely produce cartesian result.

Comment: If a user has multiple addresses it would.

Comment: no, this produces a cartesian result, regardless of the cardinality

Comment: Would this work if I pass a parameter userid to the SQLCommand and then add "where t1.userid = @userid and t2.userid = @userid" given that I also selected the userid(FK) from the address table?